# Run PHPUnit tests on change

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, gruntjs

I'd like to run my PHPUnit tests (or at least a subset of them) whenever a file changes on disk. Very similar to what you can do with "[grunt watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/README.md)". I have a project in which I have both JS and PHP, and am using Grunt. There I shell out to PHPUnit to have it run on top of my JS tests using grunt watch. While that works just fine, it seems like an awful lot of hassle to do this in a PHP only project. I'd need to introduce grunt, and add a dependency on node. Plus I have a lot of such PHP projects. A more simple solution is thus in order.

Answer (score 14):

You can use node `watch` which is quite sweet:

Run `npm init` to set up a package (takes a minute), then

```
npm install --save-dev watch
```

Then edit your `package.json` file to include these two entries:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "bin/phpunit tests --color",
  "test:watch": "watch 'npm run --silent test' ."
},
```

Then trigger the watching with:

```
npm run test:watch
```

(credit due to [this interesting article](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/))

Comment: But this would run *all* tests which in our case would mean they're running for ~20 minutes.

Comment: For windows users, had to change the ' for \" and the / for \\ like this:
    "test": "vendor\\bin\\phpunit tests --colors",
    "test:watch": "watch \"npm run --silent test\" tests"

Answer (score 6):

I've wrote a blog post on this a while back: http://edorian.github.io/2010-03-11-running-your-unit-tests-everytime-you-save-a-file/

The most basic command would be:

```
pywatch phpunit .
```

which would mean **"monitor all files in this directory and below for changes and if one of them changes run PHPUnit**".

If you have a lot of files in there (assets etc) that can get slow so a better/faster version is:

```
find -name '*.php' | xargs pywatch "./runSuite.sh"
```

which only monitors changes to `.php` files

Comment: Or just `pywatch "./runSuite.sh" ./tests/*/*.php`

Comment: I do not know how to build python package, I guess I should do something with bootstrap.py and setup.py, but can you give me some hints about it?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try `phpunit-watcher`. https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/phpunit-watcher

First, to install `phpunit-watcher` with `composer require spatie/phpunit-watcher --dev`, and then, modify the `composer.json` to add an item in `scripts` property:

```
{
    "scripts" : {
        "test" : "./vendor/bin/phpunit-watcher watch --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/"
    }
}
```

Then, you can run test cases with: `composer test`.

Sometimes, you should run `composer run test --timeout=0`, otherwise the process would be killed after 300 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

A dead simple way to do this, using inotifywait and a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  FILE=$(inotifywait --exclude=".*.*sw*" --exclude="4913" ./ --format "%w%f" -e close_write) &&
  clear &&
  phpunit --color $FILE
done
```

Then you just run that in a terminal (or however you want) and you're good.  I'm running tmux, so I just have a stacked pane set up, with a little window to see my test results.  Just run this script in the directory where your tests live.

Works well for me.

Also, this script is Vim friendly (Vim creates a file, 4913, during saves, this script ignores it).

It was totally inspired from various places around the web -- probably even from some of these answers.

Comment: This is a dead simple and great working solution. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to watch your project folder recursively, just run inotifywait with the `--recursive` option.

Answer (score 3):

In PHPStorm you can configure File Watcher that will execute shell commands for you at file modifications. For example you can have one File Watcher that will trigger on php file modification and will run phpunit command with all necessary commands.

More info about File Watchers can be found on JetBrains web help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-file-watchers.html

Answer (score 2):

Install grunt and use https://github.com/SaschaGalley/grunt-phpunit

Then you'd setup the phpunit task under with the watch task.  This is how I do it right now.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a solution to deal with this very problem: "[What's Changed?](https://icyapril.com/php/programming/2017/05/14/whats-changed-only-running-phpunit-tests-for-changed-classes.html)" In short, there are cases where you have some really large test suites and you only want to run the tests relevant to the classes which have changed.

You can pull this in via composer by running `composer require --dev icyapril/whats-changed`

With this in place just run `./vendor/bin/whatschanged` and only the file changed in your last commit or in your working directory will be run. Magic!

[image: What's Changed running successfully]

Comment: It requires `git` to be installed on the specific route by default.
`private $binary = '/usr/bin/git';`
But even with that something is not working out of the box.

https://github.com/IcyApril/WhatsChanged/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inotifywait`, see https://speakerdeck.com/rowan_m/building-better-developers-2?slide=31 for a PHPUnit example.

Comment: Had to install inotify-tools for that. Also not very Windows using colleague friendly. I'm having problems getting the thing to work properly for all PHP files in a directory. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I found the [phpunit-testrunner](https://github.com/uehondor/phpunit-testrunner) node package, which is of use for my problem. One config json file per PHP project, which can then be used by anyone that has the node package installed. Also cross platform. Still requires node though, so not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution use node+gulp

```
0. install node 
1. npm init 
2. npm install gulp --save-dev
```

create a gulpfile.js and put this

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),  
util = require('util'),
exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('phpunit', function() {
    exec('phpunit -c my_project_name/App', function(error, stdout) {
        util.puts(stdout); 
    });
}); 

gulp.task('default',['phpunit'], function() {
    gulp.watch('my_project_name/**/*.php', ['phpunit']);

});
```

my_project_name/App is the path of all source code

if add extension add this line on default task

gulp.watch('my_project_name/**/*.otherext**', ['phpunit']);

after edit php file run the phpunit test

Answer (score 0):

I've figured a one line solution based on [entr](https://github.com/eradman/entr).

```bash
find app routes tests | entr -cd php artisan test
```

It watches folders app, routes and tests, and you can add more, if you need.

Caveat is that it exits when a new file is added, so you'd need to restart it when creating a new file.