# Getting Error: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to improve my testing workflow by running my phpunit tests automatically when I make a change.

I have a local dev server on my windows machine and I am trying to run `phpunit-watch`.

```
TTY mode is not supported on windows platform.
```

I keep getting this error, is there any work around?

The plugin: https://github.com/spatie/phpunit-watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a workaround, TTY mode is not supported on windows platform, there is a reason why it is not supported.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using this strategy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226524/run-phpunit-tests-on-change

Comment: Maybe you could explain why it's not supported instead of just repeating what phpunit outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using WSL (*Windows Subsystem for Linux*). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

If you do this route, note that the file systems between Linux and Windows are different. The WSL will mount your drives which slows down performance, so if you run your command in `/mnt/c/my-folder`, it will run slower than you expect.

The only solutions I know for this so far are: Deal with it, or move your files into the Linux layer. If you move your files to the Linux system, you'll get expected speeds.

Answer (score 0):

All php artisan db does is call the MySQL command line, which you can do yourself. Check your .env file to get values for the host, username, and password. Then fill them into this command:

mysql -h host -u username -ppassword

Answer (score 0):

The `artisan test` command (and maybe other commands as well) has an option `--without-tty` that allows you to run the command from the Windows command line. Like so:

```
php artisan test --without-tty
```

Perhaps, this option has been only present in recent versions of Laravel.

I am not familiar with phpunit-watch yet, but if there is a way to configure the  commands used within it, then including this option should solve the issue.

Note: AFAIK, phpunit, itself, runs just fine from the Windows command line.  Indeed, I use it all the time.  Like so:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```